# EKS Managed Node Group with VPC-CNI Plugin

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am creating an EKS managed node group in terraform using the eks module version 17.1.0 and up until now specifying the bootstrap_extra_args like so has been working

```
    node_groups = [{
            
            name = "${var.environment}-nodes"
            desired_capacity = var.eks_cluster.desired_capacity
            max_capacity     = var.eks_cluster.max_capacity
            min_capacity     = var.eks_cluster.min_capacity
        
            additional_security_group_ids = aws_security_group.nodes.id
            instance_types                = [var.eks_cluster.node_instance_type]
            key_name = "$$$$$$"
            bootstrap_extra_args = "/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh '${local.cluster_name}' --use-max-pods false --kubelet-extra-args '--max-pods=110'"
    }]
```

I have created two clusters like this and the nodes have been created with the max pods set to 110. both of these clusters are in us-east-2

I am now trying to create a cluster in China region cn-northwest-1 and the same configuration only sets the max pods to 35 and I cannot seem to get it to go any higher.

Node types: t3a.large instances

Note: I have also attempted to launch the nodes in China with a launch_template containing the following userdata script and the script is read, there are no errors that I can find and I end up with the same result.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
#!/bin/bash -xe
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh '${cluster_name}' --use-max-pods false --kubelet-extra-args '--max-pods=110'
--//--
```

This begs the question, are eks managed node groups setup a bit differently in china? Is what I'm trying to do even possible without some crazy workaround I cannot seem to find?

Comment: Not sure I understand where the script is coming from. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The script is part of the launch_template that I tried to set for the nodes to run whenever they are created but it did not work ie it seems the nodes completely ignored the change to the configruation and I got the command and the parameters from aws documentation here
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/improvements-eks-worker-node-provisioning/

Answer (score 0):

After further testing, contrary to terraform documentation, the above definition of bootstrap_extra_args does not work and terraform does not recognize the parameter even though it does not throw any errors. The correct method is through the Launch_template set the following script in userdata

```
bootstrap_extra_args = "${local.cluster_name} --b64-cluster-ca ${module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data} --apiserver-endpoint ${module.eks.cluster_endpoint} --use-max-pods false"
```

### userdatascript.sh.tpl

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${bootstrap_extra_args}
--//--
```

without including -max-pods it will automatically set the max pods to 110

Comment: could you share how userdata.sh.tpl is getting used/referenced in the terraform code ?